# How to configure Linux to use DHCP or static IP depending on presence/absence of DHCP server?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp

I would like to configure a network interface to make use of DHCP if a DHCP server is present on the network during boot, but otherwise default to some default static IP address.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look into more complex `dhclient.conf` files.   From the man page:

> The DHCP client may decide after some period of time (see PROTOCOL TIMING) that it is 
>   not going to succeed in contacting a server. At that time, it consults its own database 
>   of old leases and tests each one that has not yet timed out by pinging the listed 
>   router for that lease to see if that lease could work. It is possible to define one or 
>   more fixed leases in the client configuration file for networks where there is no DHCP 
>   or BOOTP service, so that the client can still automatically configure its address. 
>   This is done with the lease statement.

Answer (score 1):

Normal configuration should set an address in the zero-conf IP address range if a DHCP server is not found. It may not be exactly static but will be in the 169.254.0.0/16 address range. This is a local network, but attached devices may be able to proxy access to other networks. With the avahi-discover module you may be able to find usable services. This can include web proxies, printers, and other services.

For more information see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking